# How can I remove from string the four first characters? iMacros

Tags: imacros

How can I remove from string the four first characters with iMacros.
I know it something with EVAL function but don't know how to write it.
TY

Comment: I know nothing of iMacros, but a quick look at the docs suggests `SET !SHORTENEDSTRING = EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".substr(4)")`.

Comment: Work, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of iMacros, but a quick look at the docs suggests

```
SET !SHORTENEDSTRING = EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".substr(4)")
```

The `\"` escapes the double-quote characters inside the string. `{{!EXTRACT}}` is for what was extracted by a previous iMacros statement. The `.substr(4)` is a JavaScript function: [MDN substr documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), and remember that it uses a zero-based index.